# Is it acceptable to use the same arrow icon style for two different functions on the same web page?

Tags: usability, website-design, icons

In this scenario I am using a chevron type icon for left/right navigation in a carousel to move through content. At the same time I am also using the same chevron inside buttons alongside text to indicate the button will take the user to see more content. Is this confusing? Or should I define an arrow/chevron style for left/right nav and a separate one for link clicks? From a UI standpoint I do not like having 2 different arrows on the page, but am questioning how it might affect the usability if they are the same. [In this post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79813/should-i-use-two-different-icons) a similar question is asked but it is referring to different pages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the same type of icon for different actions within a website helps to interpret the project as a well-studied set in terms of design based on an efficient graphic systematization, merely using size contrast to differentiate elements of major / minor visual entity:

[image]

If the approach is to use different icons, these should show a significant graphic contrast. A subtle formal difference between them can be interpreted more as a visual misalignment or error due to not following the same graphic guidelines:

[image]

On the contrary, if this contrast is exaggerated, the reading of both elements gains in perception regarding design and function:

[image]

Comment: When the arrows are different, make it look intentional!